# Add a "cooldown" to this Javascript that is triggered by mousewheel

Tags: javascript, squarespace

I'm working with a Squarespace theme and ran into a little bit of an experience I was hoping y'all may be able to help me fix.

The page has a series of images that scroll horizontally. By default, scrolling does nothing. The below code was provided on the forums to make the scroll control the images by clicking the left or right arrows.

I was wondering what the best and most efficient way to add a simple "cooldown" effect to the function so that there is full delay before the next scroll.

Currently, the scroll just cycles through 3 or four and is very sensitive. I feel that would annoy users.

Thank you in adv for any help. Here's the page in question: http://nicpadula.com/brand-design

```
 <script>
 $(function() {
   $("body").mousewheel(function(event, deltaY) {
     if (deltaY > 0){
       $(document).ready(function()
       {
         $("div.arrow-wrapper.left").click(); 
       });
     }
     else if (deltaY < 0){
       $(document).ready(function()
       {
         $("div.arrow-wrapper.right").click(); 
       });
     }
   });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Plenty of libraries that do debounce or throttle. FYI, those document ready calls in the middle of that are useless. They do nothing, remove them.

Comment: It would help if you included the event listener for the arrow button clicks - depending on how the animation is implemented, you could probably simply return if the animation is still happening. Alternatively you could use one of those libraries suggested by epascarello, or have a variable that stores date.getTime() and check against it within the mousewheel function.